# Sequence of positive integers $n$ such that $n^2+n+1$ divides $4^n+2^n+1$ and $n$ is not power two

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If positive integer $n$ is not power two and $n^2+n+1 \mid 4^n+2^n+1$, then what sequence of $n$?

Source problem from [Prove that there are infinitely many integers $n>0$ such that $n^2+n+1$ divides $4^n+2^n+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253964/prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-integers-n0-such-that-n2n1-divides).

We have two first term of sequence: `215,3692374808`.

Let $m=n^2+n+1$. For both first terms $m$ is prime.

Question 1: can be $m$ is not prime for next terms?

Suppose 1: $m$ is prime $\overset{FLT}{\implies} 2^{n(n+1)}\equiv 1 \pmod{m} \implies 2^{3n}\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$.

Question 2: how prove if $m$ is prime then $n\equiv2\pmod{3}$?

Note: from post [Modular arithmetic with Legendre symbol](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269654/modular-arithmetic-with-legendre-symbol) implies $n\not\equiv1\pmod3$.

Suppose 2: $n\equiv2\pmod{3} \implies 2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{3}}\equiv3^{\frac{n(n+1)}{3}}\equiv n^x\pmod{m}$, where some integer $x\ge0$.

Question 3: what other conditions for $n$ we can seen for speedup find next terms?

Comment: Please define all data here, without reference to the "other post", which is itself hard to compile. So we have "two term"(s) of *which sequence*? Please start the question in the text not (only) in the title. So what is $n$, that then determines some $m$. "Next terms" are the terms of which sequence? Abbreviations like FLT over arrows make the question even less readable. What do we suppose? That $m$ (still undefined) is prime? That first implication arrow holds? That both implications hold? Moreover, here we have a lot of questions, but no word on motivation and own tries, not on this site.

Comment: The latter is a form of the former evaluated at $2^n$ .