# Modular arithmetic with Legendre symbol

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ and let $p\neq3$ be a prime divisor of $n^2+n+1$. Show that $p\equiv1\mod3$.

I thought of trying to prove that $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=1$, since 1 is the only element of $\mathbb{F}_3$ that is a square modulo 3. I am supposed to use quadratic reciprocity, which leads to $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$. However, I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: I think you meant $1$ is the only element of $\Bbb F_3^\color{red}*$ that is a square

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $4(n^2+n+1)=(2n+1)^2+3$ is divisible by $p$, we have $-3$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.  So
\begin{align*}
1=\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)&=\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)(-1)^{(p-1)/2}\\
&=\left(\frac{p}{3}\vphantom{\frac3p}\right)(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\cdot\frac{3-1}{2}}(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}&&\text{Quadratic Reciprocity}\\
&=\left(\frac{p}{3}\vphantom{\frac3p}\right)
\end{align*}
So $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we have to rule out prime divisor $2$ : $$n^2+n=n(n+1)$$ is always even hence $$n^2+n+1$$ is always odd.

Suppose $$p\mid n^2+n+1$$

Then $$p\mid 4n^2+4n+4=(2n+1)^2+3$$

hence $$(2n+1)^2\equiv -3\mod p$$

Now, if $$p\equiv 1\mod 4$$ we get $$(\frac{3}{p})=(\frac{-1}{p})\cdot (\frac{-3}{p})=1\cdot 1=1$$ It follows $$(\frac{p}{3})=1$$

And if $$p\equiv 3\mod 4$$ we get $$(\frac{3}{p})=(\frac{-1}{p})\cdot (\frac{-3}{p})=(-1)\cdot 1=-1$$ It follows again $$(\frac{p}{3})=1$$

Comment: Note the title "with Legendre symbol" and "I am supposed to use QR".